# can't understand submit form in React JS tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the submit function for react JS tutorial [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)
I can't understand the success function, because data is supposed to be an array. Yet on success, its overriding the array with a singular comment.

I'm using this code and overriding this array with one comment means the map function doesn't work, and it breaks it all.

Why is seemingly incorrect code in the tutorial and how do I fix it?

also, what is a better function than Date.now() for the comment id?

```
handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    // Optimistically set an id on the new comment. It will be replaced by an
    // id generated by the server. In a production application you would likely
    // not use Date.now() for this and would have a more robust system in place.
    comment.id = Date.now();
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: comments});
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

Comment: The `data` in the `success` is not a singular comment, but an array of comments returned from the server. For comment id you can use UUID/GUID which will be a unique value which can be persisted on a database

Comment: I'm using Django Rest Framework for serialization, so a POST just returns the comment submitted, and a GET returns them all. How would I fix it in this case? - in the javascript side. I could obviously alter the server which I don't want to do

Comment: I am not familiar with the Django Framework, but i'd think you should be able to return all the comments from a POST as well.

Comment: is there a way to do this in the javascript side? if so which way is better?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I thought it was a client side problem, I fixed it by changing the response from my server to be an array.

I won't mark this answer as accepted though as I believe there could be a client side way of solving this?

using DRF, and a custom viewset, I had to change the create view to return the same as the list view

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    object_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    object_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    object_serializer.save()
    headers = self.get_success_headers(object_serializer.data)

    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```